# Why is the SpeechToText recognizer in floating window not working?

Tags: java, android

When I open up an application, I have a simple button which, when pressed, opens up the new intent for floating window. The floating window has a image on it which, when pressed, will listen to voice by using onclick listener. Voice to text then uses intent operation and give the results.

This procedure works fine without any error as long as the starting application is not excluded from recent activity. If I put a code to exclude the application from recents on On create method or in Manifest, the speechtotext recognizer in floating window doesn't seems to be working when I open some other application (say instagram/whatsapp), and try to run this floating window speechtotext (no beep sound). However it works well if I remove the code exclude from recents.

Also, I don't want the application to be shown in recent activity when floating window starts!

This is my code for oncreate to exclude the app from recents. I also tried by putting in manifest file.

```java
ActivityManager RfR = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE); 
if(RfR != null) { 
    List<ActivityManager.AppTask> tasks = RfR.getAppTasks(); 
    if (tasks != null && tasks.size() > 0 { 
        tasks.get(0).setExcludeFromRecents(true); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is My code for oncreate to exclude the app from recents. also i tried by putting in manifest file.                            ActivityManager RfR = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE); if(RfR != null) { List<ActivityManager.AppTask> tasks = RfR.getAppTasks(); if (tasks != null && tasks.size() > 0) { tasks.get(0).setExcludeFromRecents(true); } }.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65154985/edit) your question with your code. [How to do formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) And you should always state what targetSDK you are using and how you are testing (emulator/device-model OS version).

Answer (score 0):

Working with floating window is a bit tricky. You can't be sure when it will be shut down by the OS. In your case you can't run the `floating` window `service` after removing the app from the `recent apps` in many devices. I said many devices because in some devices it will work even after removing the app from the `recent apps`. This is how it is. It depends on the phone manufacture weather the floating window gonna work or not after removing the app from `recent apps`.
I have an app with over a million downloads that totally works on floating window service and i have came across this issue a long time ago.